# Seeking a noun for 'one who acts with the wellbeing of people and planet in mind'

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm looking for a noun to describe a person who lives in a way that actively benefits people and planet, or at least lives in a way that does no harm.
 '**Altruist**' is the closest I've got so far, but a) perhaps it has anthropocentric connotations and b) I'd like a more commonly used word, that most readers would understand.

Comment: A lot of words like benevolent, big-hearted, kind, compassionate fit your context arguably well. Please consider adding more details and an usage example so that you can narrow down on the possible answers.

Comment: If you eventually decide that there’s perhaps no perfect noun, you could form a compound adjective to modify “person” by sticking “[-]conscious” after the most appropriate word (or abbreviation thereof as in, for the environment (& the people in it?), “an [eco-conscious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eco%E2%80%93conscious) person”). Using such an adjective might convey (or at least allow) the “at least … does no harm” notion better than a specific noun that could perhaps [over-]emphasize the “actively benefits” notion more than you really seem to want to.

Answer (score 2):

You should check ***philanthropist***.

M-W:

> **[philanthropist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/philanthropist)**
>   *noun*
>
> one who makes an active effort to promote human welfare :  a person
>   who practices philanthropy

Comment: This answer seems very anthropocentric, a connotation the OP doesn't want. Nevertheless, it is a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

***Environmentalist*** may be a good fit, as this relates more to the state of the planet and is less centred on humans.

> 1 :  an advocate of environmentalism
>
> 2 :  one concerned about environmental quality especially of the human
>   environment with respect to the control of pollution

([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/environmentalist))